# Why does my query returns 0 rows using LIKE with php PDO

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, pdo

so I have this ajax keyup search event in my js

```
$("#search").keyup(function(){
    var searchText = $('#search').val();
    var searchBy = $('#searchBy').val();
    var newObj = {  action: "search", 
                    searchText: searchText,
                    searchBy: searchBy
                }
    $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        url:"../_tasklogger/classes/tasklog-functions.php", //the page containing php script
        dataType: 'html',
        data: newObj,
        success: function(response){                   
            $("#taskTable").html(response);
        },
        error: function (req, status, err) {
            console.log('Something went wrong', status, err, req);
        }
    });
});
```

which calls this php function below:

```
$searchText = $_POST['searchText'];
$searchBy = $_POST['searchBy'];
$limit = 5;
    $sql =  "SELECT *
            FROM tasks
            WHERE userId = :userid and :searchby LIKE :searchtext
            LIMIT :datalimit";
    $stmt = $db_con->prepare($sql);
    $searchText = $searchText."%";
    $stmt->bindParam(":userid", $_SESSION['userid']);
    $stmt->bindParam(":searchby", $searchBy);
    $stmt->bindParam(":searchtext", $searchText, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(":datalimit", $limit, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    if($stmt->execute()){
        echo'<tr>
                <th>Date</th>
                <th>Task Name</th>
                <th>Duration</th>
                <th>Start Time</th>
                <th>End Time</th>
                <th colspan="2" style="text-align:center;">Action</th>
            </tr>';
        while ($row = $stmt->fetch()){
            echo '<tr>';
            echo    '<td>'.$row['taskDate'].'</td>';
            echo    '<td>'.$row['taskName'].'</td>';
            echo    '<td>'.$row['duration'].'</td>';
            echo    '<td>'.$row['startTime'].'</td>';
            echo    '<td>'.$row['endTime'].'</td>';
            echo    '<td> 
                        <button id="editbtn" value="'.$row['taskId'].'" class="btn waves-effect waves-light orange lighten-1 hoverable">Edit</button> 
                    </td>';
            echo    '<td> 
                        <button id="deletebtn" value="'.$row['taskId'].'" class="btn waves-effect waves-light red lighten-1 hoverable">Delete</button> 
                    </td>';
            echo '</tr>';
        }
    }
```

But it does not return anything. I have tested the query in the database and it works fine. I think the thing that is causing the problem is in my `$searchText` variable.

Thank you for anyone that can help me!

Comment: Where does `$searchText` come from? Is this PHP code being executed in a loop? What is the value just before executing the query? Make sure you enable PDO error [error handling](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php). Did you check the AJAX return value to see if any errors are being outputted?

Comment: sorry i did not added the POST value where `$searchText` comes from. No it's not executed in a loop it will just be called by a simple ajax request (which is the keyup event). Yes I enabled the PDO error handling. I've checked the return value but weirdly it does not output any errors or I must have missed the error.

Comment: What is the value of `$searchText`? What is the HTTP response code?

Comment: Actually it passed the `if($stmt->execute())` condition so it means it does not have any errors. But is `$searchText = $searchText."%";` works?

Comment: The HTTP response code is OK 200. I think it must have been something in declaring my `$searchText` value with `%` in it.

Comment: @zynx sun use try { } catch { } to show any error. Might be some variable is not coming or empty. Echo out the variables and then  see what is coming to you,

Answer (score 0):

Understanding PDO like statements:

This is WRONG:

```
 "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `name` LIKE '%:key%'";
```

The CORRECT solution is to leave clean the placeholder like this:

```
 "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `name` LIKE :key";
```

And then add the percentages to the php variable where you store the keyword:

```
$key= "%".$key."%";
```

Reference php PDO manual.

Hope it helps you.